# Wireless Range Extender. Need upto 1 Mile line of sight

Tags: wireless-networking, signal-strength

I've been shopping online for a good wireless range extender. I have a workshop located approximately 500 feet from my house (network) and a grain dryer which I would like to have wireless access near which is located about 2000 feet from my network.

I've looked at [Ayrstone AyrMesh™](http://www.ayrstone.com/products.html) and it appears to be what i'm looking for, however the price is pretty steep. Can anyone suggest a product that they have used that may fit my needs?

Comment: Build a simple parabolic antenna system. There are several DIY kits for this online that apparently work quite well for line of site communication.

Comment: Any PC wireless solution with up to 1 mile range is going to be expensive. Only other solution is fiber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the workshop powered by an AC feed from the house (ie: on the same power phase)? If so, homeplug-type power adaptors typically work up to about 300m (about 980 feet).

For the grain dryer you will either need to do trial-and-error with directional antennas on standard wifi kit (might get about 1Mbit at that distance), but remember that it's no good having a directional high-gain antenna on one end and expecting a laptop or handheld device to 'make it' back too - you'll need a point-to-point link setup to bring the wireless to the grain store and then a local access point to distribute it.